# How to add class to dynamically created row in asp.net mvc using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table

```
<table id="dataTable" style="width: 80%; border: none">
<tbody>
    <tr class="CurrentRow">
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].SUN_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "sunhrs" }
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></tr></table>
```

and another table

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="AddRow>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].SUN_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;" }
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></tr></table>
```

Now I am adding row to "Currentclass" using "Addrow" class like

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {

    var template = $('.AddRow').clone()

    template.find('input[type=text]').val('');
    $.each(template.find('input[type=text]'), function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        name = name.replace('0', count - 1);
        $(this).attr('name', name);
    });

    $("#dataTable").append(template);
    template.removeClass('AddRow').addClass('CurrentRow').show();

});
```

Now, I want to add class 'sunhrs' for 'datatable'with newly created row textboxes on button click. I have tried like

```
 var currentTemplate = $("#dataTable").clone();
 currentTemplate.find('input[type=text]').addClass('sunhrs')
```

But Not working, Please help me anyone.

Comment: Maybe a typo, but you have an extra ending `tr` tag between your tbody and table end tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#dataTable").append(template);
$("#dataTable .AddRow").addClass('CurrentRow').removeClass('AddRow').show();
```

Comment: Adding rows, but not adding class 'sunhrs' to textbox? @Milind Anantwar

Comment: Try it after appending the content.

Answer (score 0):

This Code is Working Fine-

```
 $("#dataTable").append(template);
 $("#dataTable .AddRow").find('input[type=text]').addClass('sunhrs');
 $("#dataTable .AddRow").addClass('CurrentRow').removeClass('AddRow').show();
```